# What's the meaning of "Already up-to-date"

Tags: git, merge

When I create a remote repository in git ,"Merge the changes from upstream/master into your local master branch. This brings your fork's master branch into sync with the upstream repository, without losing your local changes."

[image]

What's the meaning of "Already up-to-date";

Comment: It means your files are exactly the same as the lastest version in the repository

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at two common situations where you get the above message.

The first one occurs with a commit graph that looks like this:

```
... - o - o - o - *   <-- HEAD=master, upstream/master
```

That is, *your* latest commit is the one marked with an asterisk `*`, *their* latest commit is the very same commit, and therefore there is nothing to merge.  That's a very typical case and is the one I think DolphinJava means.

A different case occurs with a graph that looks like this:

```
... - o - o - Y - *   <-- HEAD=master
            \   /
              o       <-- upstream/master
```

Here *your* latest commit is again the one marked `*`: it's the result of a merge.  *Their* latest commit is the lower-line node `o`.  The commit marked `Y` is exclusively "yours" (hence the Y).

In order to *get to* this second graph, you (or someone—see below) must have already done an earlier `git merge`, which created the merge commit `*`.  If, however, at this point you do a *second* `git merge` it will say `Already up-to-date`.

In this particular case, your latest commit (`git rev-parse HEAD` will show you the raw SHA-1) will differ from their latest commit (`git rev-parse upstream/master` will show you that one's raw SHA-1), even though you are "up to date".  If you remember that you did an earlier merge, you might expect this, but if you've forgotten (or if someone else has direct access to your repository and *they* did the merge, without telling you), this might be a surprise.

It's also possible to get to a state like this in the (rare and kind of annoying, really) case when someone at the upstream deletes a merge commit, "rewriting history" on their end.  Whether you will ever see this depends on who controls that upstream and how they do things.

To view the actual commit graph, use `git log --all --graph` or `gitk --all` or some other graph viewer.